# Dynamic SQL: ORA-00925 and ORA-06512

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This code makes no sense, just for training. But here are such errors, when calling this:

```
EXEC ADD_ROW( 'fds', 'hgd', '243-650-215', 2);
```

1 ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword
ORA-06512: at "MYDB.ADD_ROW", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 2 Procedure:MYDB.ADD_ROW(MyDB@localhost:ORCL) 8 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.add_row(
  v1 IN CLIENT.FNAME%TYPE, v2 IN CLIENT.LNAME%TYPE, v3 IN CLIENT.DOC_ID%TYPE, v4 IN CLIENT.BENEFIT_ID%TYPE)
  IS
  sql_stmnt VARCHAR(200);
  tab_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'CLIENT';
  BEGIN
    sql_stmnt := 'INSERT INTO' || tab_name ||  'VALUES(100, :1,:2,:3,:4)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmnt USING  v1, v2, v3, v4;
  END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing a space either side of this: `' || tab_name ||  '`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYDB.add_row(
  v1 IN CLIENT.FNAME%TYPE, v2 IN CLIENT.LNAME%TYPE, v3 IN CLIENT.DOC_ID%TYPE, v4 IN CLIENT.BENEFIT_ID%TYPE)
  IS
  sql_stmnt VARCHAR(200);
  tab_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'CLIENT';
  BEGIN
    sql_stmnt := 'INSERT INTO ' || tab_name ||  ' VALUES(100, :1,:2,:3,:4)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmnt USING  v1, v2, v3, v4;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing spaces around your table name. This code will generate an SQL of the form `INSERT INTOmy_tableVALUES(100, :1,:2,:3,:4)`

Just modify the sql generation:

```
sql_stmnt := 'INSERT INTO ' || tab_name ||  ' VALUES(100, :1,:2,:3,:4)';
```